# How to get the white space in xsd?

Tags: xsd

Following is the code snippet :

```
<xs:element name="A_Record">
    <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="A8_Filler" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="A10_ReferenceNumber" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="A11b_EffectiveDate" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="A11c_Filler" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

I need to have whitespaces in A8_Filler, A11b_EffectiveDate and A11c_Filler. How can I do this?

Comment: Need more information, Your question very poorly constructed.

Comment: I need the element A8_filler , A11c_filler to have whitespace. How to do this?

Comment: have you tried using  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
    </xs:restriction> into element?

Comment: could you please show me the code snippet for it?

Answer (score 1):

Turning krio's comment into an answer, try:

```
<xs:element name="A_Record">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="A8_Filler">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A10_ReferenceNumber" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="A11b_EffectiveDate">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A11c_Filler">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

... or even create a reusable type:

```
<xs:element name="A_Record">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="A8_Filler" type="MyWhitespaceStringType" />
            <xs:element name="A10_ReferenceNumber" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="A11b_EffectiveDate" type="MyWhitespaceStringType" />
            <xs:element name="A11c_Filler" type="MyWhitespaceStringType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="MyWhitespaceStringType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```